# Ruby on Rails creation of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I created two controller and view named

```
rails new generate controller home page
rails new generate controller login index
```

created a model named login and the code is

```
class Login
include Mongoid::Document
field :username, type: String
field :password, type: String
end
```

home controllers page action contains the code

```
<%= link_to "Enter Details",controller: "login" %>
```

login_controller contains

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
def index
@log=Login.new
end
end
```

and login controllers index action contains the code for form

```
<%= form_for(@log) do |l| %>
<%= l.label :USERNAME %><br>
<%= l.text_field %> <br>

<%= l.label :PASSWORD %><br>
<%= l.text_field %><br>

<%= l.submit :LOGIN %>
<% end %>
```

After executing it gives me an error and the screen is [here](http://i.cubeupload.com/GVGzwL.jpg).

And my routes.rb file contains the following codes.

```
new_project::Application.routes.draw do
get "login/index"
get "home/page"
resources :products
root 'home#page'
end
```

where did i went wrong .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `form_for` using a POST method to send a data. In your routes you have only GET route for login action. If you want to use RESTful routes, add this line

```
resource :login
```

if you want to add only index/create routes

```
resource :login, :only => [:index, :create]
```

[More info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) about rails routing.

Comment: but the get route in the file is automatically added . i didn't did anything . If i typed any values in the text box and hit the button that should be the time the error occurs isn't it.? But the error occurs right after when i click the "ENTER DETAILS" link .

Comment: nope, when you click 'enter details' link, you proceed to the page with incorrect form which rails cannot build

Comment: Oh .. yeah i got it now.